# Calender - jQuery works on stand along but not when on a .aspx page with a master page

Tags: jquery, html, vb.net

I have a calender program that works and searches. The jQuery by default pushes the date the user selects to the input box.

```
<input type="hidden" id="datepickerFrom" />
```

As far as I know you can not get this value out when doing a search (if you can then that resolves the following issue)

I have then moved the jQuery, CSS and text/label boxes into the main program but when I click on the calender function it shows the calender, fills in the input box as per above. (I unhid this to check)

In my stand alone version I the date goes to

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="lblDateStart" runat="server" width="120px" />
```

the jQuery is based in a js file in folder and is clearly being referenced or nothing would work.

The code that fills both in is below. I have been playing for a couple of courses going back and forth.

I have tried putting the CSS/jQuery references in the master and .aspx file to see it is made a difference as well as putting the jQuery onto the page itself (messy but a good test).

So CSS and referencing work from what I can work out. The error is feeding back to the page, but only for the textbox.

Code that is triggered on calender date click...

```
//Varibles passed out here from the functions as we can not check inputs
var lblDateStart = '<%= lblDateStart.ClientId %>';
function setLabelStart(yourDate1) {
    $("#lblDateStart").val(yourDate1);
}

var lblDateEnd = '<%= lblDateEnd.ClientId %>';
function setLabelEnd(yourDate2) {
    $("#lblDateEnd").val(yourDate2);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepickerFrom").datepicker({
        //display month drop down
        changeMonth: true,
        //display year drop down
        changeYear: true,
        //date format
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        //calender image
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "../images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        //multiple months
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        //show 'done' button
        //showButtonPanel: true,
        // Default Date
        defaultDate: "-4w",
        //pass value to variable
        onSelect: setLabelStart
    });
});

//More than one date? You need to scripts

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepickerTo").datepicker({
        //display month drop down
        changeMonth: true,
        //display year drop down
        changeYear: true,
        //date format
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        //calender image
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "../images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        //multiple months
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        //show 'done' button
        //showButtonPanel: true,
        // Default Date
        defaultDate: "+0w",
        //pass value to variable
        onSelect: setLabelEnd
    });
});
```

So I now need a little guidance, if you want any more detail let me know. :-)

I suspect it might be to do with the below ClientID line but that might be a red herring?

var lblDateEnd = '<%= lblDateEnd.ClientId %>';

Comment: Show the markup for datepickerTo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using your variables as a constant so any element will match the selector, instead of this:

```
var lblDateStart = '<%= lblDateStart.ClientId %>';
function setLabelStart(yourDate1) {
    $("#lblDateStart").val(yourDate1);
}

var lblDateEnd = '<%= lblDateEnd.ClientId %>';
function setLabelEnd(yourDate2) {
    $("#lblDateEnd").val(yourDate2);
}
```

use this:

```
var lblDateStart = '#<%= lblDateStart.ClientId %>';
function setLabelStart(yourDate1) {
    $(lblDateStart).val(yourDate1);
}

var lblDateEnd = '#<%= lblDateEnd.ClientId %>';
function setLabelEnd(yourDate2) {
    $(lblDateEnd).val(yourDate2);
}
```

as you can see the # is contained in the selector variable to get the value of the matched element.

Comment: No joy sadly, it is within <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server"> does that make a difference?

Comment: Maybe I need to add #ctl00_MainContent_ ??

Comment: When I use your code the stand alone version (and the version within other code) does not display in lblDateStart or lblDateEnd. If I go back the standalone works. I rechecked the code in IE and Chrome to same affect.

Comment: Apologies for any confussion. If the code is on a page without a masterpage it works, but add a masterpage and this ContentPlaceHolders then it does not work.

Comment: For me is working fine, in a master page context you have to use #<%=lblDateStart.ClientID%> as selector because the element id is changed by the page rendering (I'll add this comment to the answwer)

Comment: I ma placing the above code in the  external jQuery code. Do I need anything on the master/aspx page? Have I missed the obvious?

Comment: I needed to reference the content placeholder... var lblDateEnd = '<%= #lblDateEnd.ClientId %>';
function setLabelEnd(yourDate2) {
    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblDateEnd").val(yourDate2);
}

Comment: Using the code #<%=lblDateStart.ClientID%> the aspx variable part is replaced from the page compilation. If you have an external script it can't work. You have to include the script inside the page or use the calcutated id by checking it in the inspector.

Comment: Last favour, and thank you you have been a great help. Can you confirm what I wrote below is the best way so I am not misleading myself or others.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly a big thank you to Edward. The issue I had was trying to get a jQuery value into a textbox.

What I found was it worked in a .aspx page when there was not a master page. However add a master page and you add a contentplaceholder.

In my mind the contentplaceholder acts and feels much like a sub-folder, or dare I say it - an iframe (but without the hellish implications).

So the solution, whereever you have a label, text box etc.. on a page, but in a contentplaceholder and the value is not passing though:

1) Open the page in IE 
2) View Source
3) Copy the ID IE has given the Label (it will have changed)
4) Make this the target

i.e. I at first (in error) targetted

```
   $("#lblDateEnd").val(yourDate2);
```

but actually I needed to add firstly "ct100_" this always goes at the front

Then add the placeholder name, in my case "ContentPlaceHolder_"

note the underscores, they are like forward slahes for folders

and finally it will work...

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblDateEnd").val(yourDate2);
```